# How do keep only unique words within each string in a vector

Tags: r, string, vector, duplicates

I have data that looks like this:

```
vector = c("hello I like to code hello","Coding is fun", "fun fun fun")
```

I want to remove duplicate words (space delimited) i.e. the output should look like

vector_cleaned

```
[1] "hello I like to code"
[2] "coding is fun"
[3] "fun"
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Split it up (`strsplit` on spaces), use `unique` (in `lapply`), and `paste` it back together:

```
vapply(lapply(strsplit(vector, " "), unique), paste, character(1L), collapse = " ")
# [1] "hello i like to code" "coding is fun"        "fun"  

## OR
vapply(strsplit(vector, " "), function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = " "), character(1L))
```

---

#### Update based on comments

You can always write a custom function to use with your `vapply` function. For instance, here's a function that takes a split string, drops strings that are shorter than a certain number of characters, and has the "unique" setting as a user choice.

```
myFun <- function(x, minLen = 3, onlyUnique = TRUE) {
  a <- if (isTRUE(onlyUnique)) unique(x) else x
  paste(a[nchar(a) > minLen], collapse = " ")
}
```

Compare the output of the following to see how it would work.

```
vapply(strsplit(vector, " "), myFun, character(1L))
vapply(strsplit(vector, " "), myFun, character(1L), onlyUnique = FALSE)
vapply(strsplit(vector, " "), myFun, character(1L), minLen = 0)
```

Comment: can I apply this same technique to remove any words in the split string that have less than 3 characters?

Comment: @shecode, the approach would be similar, but you would have to add one more requirement based on the result of `nchar` (which would count the number of characters in the string). On my phone right now, so I can't show the code, but I'll try to update later. Ideally, if I do so, the question should also be updated.

Comment: Thankyou. I figured it out how to do it based on the structure of your answer. very useful

Answer (score 2):

I spent a while looking for a data frame, tidyverse-friendly version of this, so figured I'd paste my verbose solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(vector = c("hello I like to code hello",
                            "Coding is fun", 
                            "fun fun fun"))

df %>% 
  mutate(split = str_split(vector, " ")) %>% # split
  mutate(split = map(.$split, ~ unique(.x))) %>% # drop duplicates
  mutate(split = map_chr(.$split, ~paste(.x, collapse = " "))) # recombine
```

Result:

```r
#>                       vector                split
#> 1 hello I like to code hello hello I like to code
#> 2              Coding is fun        Coding is fun
#> 3                fun fun fun                  fun
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>% 
   separate_longer_delim(vector, delim = regex("\\s+")) %>%
   distinct() %>%
   reframe(vector = str_c(vector, collapse = " "), .by = c("rn")) %>% 
  select(-rn)
```

-output

```
                vector
1 hello I like to code
2        Coding is fun
3                  fun
```