# How to extract unique values within each row in dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, unique, delimited

I am trying to extract unique values within each rows of dataframe in R without using for loop.

```
df <- data.frame(customer = c('joe','jane','john','mary'), fruit = c('orange, apple, orange', NA, 'apple', 'orange, orange'))

df

  customer                 fruit
1      joe orange, apple, orange
2     jane                  <NA>
3     john                 apple
4     mary        orange, orange
```

What I want for the `fruit` column is:
'orange, apple', NA, 'apple', 'orange'

```
  customer                 fruit
1      joe         orange, apple
2     jane                  <NA>
3     john                 apple
4     mary                orange
```

I tried something along the lines of

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) unique(unlist(str_split(x[, "fruit"], ", "))))
```

and it is not working.

How can I get unique values within each row in the dataframe?

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28033312/680068

Answer (score 4):

Base R option :

Split the string on comma, keep unique values and paste the values into comma-separated string.

```
df$fruit <- sapply(strsplit(df$fruit, ',\\s+'), function(x) toString(unique(x)))
df

#  customer         fruit
#1      joe orange, apple
#2     jane            NA
#3     john         apple
#4     mary        orange
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple pipe syntax using `dplyr` and `purrr::map`

```
df %>% mutate(fruit = str_split(fruit, ", "),
              fruit = map(fruit, ~ unique(.x)))
  customer         fruit
1      joe orange, apple
2     jane            NA
3     john         apple
4     mary        orange
```

or BaseR only

```
df$fruit <- Map(unique, strsplit(df$fruit, ", "))
df

> df
  customer         fruit
1      joe orange, apple
2     jane            NA
3     john         apple
4     mary        orange
```

**Note: Assumption that every string is separated by a comma and a space as shown in sample**

Comment: I have a quick question, I gave your first suggestion a try and it worked for my case but the outputs that contain commas return the values in the following form c("Case1","Case2"). Can I add another argument so that the output is just a string separated by commas?

Comment: As an update I tried adding %>% unnest(cols = c(fruit)) but end up losing everything after the first case

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Solution**
I just modified my code to match what you would like your output to be.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  separate_rows(fruit) %>%
  distinct(customer, fruit) %>%
  group_by(customer) %>%
  summarise(fruit = paste(sort(fruit, na.last = FALSE), collapse = ", "))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
  customer fruit        
  <chr>    <chr>        
1 jane     NA           
2 joe      apple, orange
3 john     apple        
4 mary     orange
```

Comment: I am so new to this site that it took me a while to edit the OP.. Thanks so much for your answer. It looks really promising! Would there be a way to keep the unique values per customer? I edited to show what I want. From your answer, I guess I can group_by(customer) and then go from there?

Comment: I modified it, so that we have delimited unique values in each row by each customer.

Answer (score 0):

here is a potential solution using base R, no libraries. Lots of ugly brackets but I think it works..

```
df$fruit <-lapply(1:nrow(df),function(n)unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(df$fruit[n],",")))))
```

output as follows

```
> df
  customer         fruit
1      joe orange, apple
2     jane            NA
3     john         apple
4     mary        orange
```

Comment: The `apply` Function is designed to apply functions across the rows or columns of an object. `lapply` is for lists  you’ve just worked around that.